# Is it possible to access document.body.scrollHeight with the chromeless API?

Tags: javascript, chromeless

I would like to capture a fullpage screenshot using the chromless api. (Fullpage as in everything below the fold, not just the current viewport.

In order to do this, I think one would calculate the height of the webpage (using `document.body.scrollHeight`), and set the viewport height to that value.

Here is what I currently have, I am testing on their [demo site](http://chromeless.netlify.com/):

```
const chromeless = new Chromeless({ remote: true })

const screenshot = await chromeless
  .goto('https://www.graph.cool')
  .setViewport({width: 1024, height: 800, scale: 1})
  .evaluate(() => {
    const height = document.body.scrollHeight;
    return height
    })
  .setViewport({width: 1024, height: height, scale: 1})
  .screenshot()

console.log(screenshot)

await chromeless.end()
```

I think (hope) my javascript is okay, and maybe this is a limitation of the API? Is the `document` object accessible from a headless web browser?

Here is the documentation on evaluate for reference:
https://github.com/graphcool/chromeless/blob/master/docs/api.md#api-evaluate

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to screenshot the full page by grabbing the document's height like this ([demo](http://chromeless.netlify.com/#src=const%20chromeless%20=%20new%20Chromeless(%7B%20remote:%20true%20%7D)%0A%0Aconst%20scrollHeight%20=%20await%20chromeless%0A%20%20.goto('https://www.graph.cool')%0A%20%20.evaluate(()%20=%3E%20document.body.scrollHeight)%0A%0Aconsole.log(%60The%20document's%20height%20is%20$%7BscrollHeight%7Dpx%60)%0A%0Aconst%20screenshot%20=%20await%20chromeless%0A%20%20.setViewport(%7Bwidth:%201024,%20height:%20scrollHeight,%20scale:%201%7D)%0A%20%20.screenshot()%0A%0Aconsole.log(screenshot)%0A%0Aawait%20chromeless.end()%0A)):

```js
const chromeless = new Chromeless({ remote: true })

const scrollHeight = await chromeless
  .goto('https://www.graph.cool')
  .evaluate(() => document.body.scrollHeight)

console.log(`The document's height is ${scrollHeight}px`)

const screenshot = await chromeless
  .setViewport({width: 1024, height: scrollHeight, scale: 1})
  .screenshot()

console.log(screenshot)

await chromeless.end()
```

The main thing to note is that we have to return the height from the `evaluate()` call and assign that to a variable `scrollHeight` which we can then use to set the viewport's height.